# Is there a Vuejs equivalent for LINQ?

Tags: javascript, linq, vue.js

I'm new to javascript and i just wanted to know if there is a LinQ equivalent in vue. My goal is to do something like this :

```
this.selection = this.clientsComplete.Where(
        c => c.id == eventArgs.sender.id);
```

On a collection made like this :

```
clientsComplete: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "Client1",
          description: "Unknown",
          sites: [
            { id: 1, title: "Site1-1", description: "Unknown" },
            { id: 2, title: "Site1-2", description: "Unknown" }
          ]
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "Client2",
          description: "Inconnue",
          sites: [
            { id: 1, title: "Site2-1", description: "Unknown" },
    ...
```

Is this event possible in vue? I can't find anything in the documentation about selection in Lists.

If there is no LinQ equivalent, do I have to do a foreach to find my object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using plain javascript? There are powerful array functions that can get you there.

For example:

`this.clientsComplete.filter(c => c.id == eventArgs.sender.id)` is very similar to what LINQ Where does.

[More info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Edit: this uses [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) but it can also be written without it.

Comment: Exactly, wanted to write the same thing, you beat me to it @paqash ;-). But indeed the built in methods can make you go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/manipula is javascript LINQ equivalent. Example:

```
this.selection = Manipula.from(this.clientsComplete)
                         .where(c=> c.id == eventArgs.sender.id)
                         .toArray();
```